# How to select loops with 'emulate 3 button mouse' and 'LMB select' enabled?

Tags: selection-tools

Is there a way to select loops with *Emulate 3 Button Mouse* and *Left click select* enabled?

Comment: What about `Shift+Alt+LMB`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer gandalf3, but it doesn`t work :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also create a keyboard shortcut in User Preferences > Input. Then expand 3D View > Mesh and click Add New. Enter `mesh.loop_select` as the identifier and set up your shortcut. I use `[`. Tick the checkbox for "Toggle Select".

In 2.7 it will act like the `L` and allow you to multi-select! You can hover and press `[` and it will act exactly like if you `ALT + RMB` without Emulate mouse on.

The answer iKlsR gave is good but it won't behave the same; selecting a face and going Select > Edge Loop will select 2 face loops, which is rarely what you want.

Answer (score 15):

In blender 2.8 it is double left click to select a loop if the *Emulate 3 Button Mouse* is checked in settings.

Answer (score 4):

In Blender 2.8, it's **shift** + double left click if emulate 3 button mouse is enabled. ;)

Answer (score 2):

*Emulate MMB* [does not currently work](http://developer.blender.org/T37735) when you choose *select with LMB*. Blender allows you to select it when it's grayed but it still wont work.

[image]

To select an edge loop, use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>LMB</kbd> or from the view header, select an edge and go to *Select > Edge Loop*. Additionally, you can map a custom shortcut to this action by right clicking and choosing *Change Shortcut*.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Blender 3.0.0 Alpha in Windows 10 it's also shift + double left click when 'emulate 3 button mouse' and left click to select are enabled. In macOS Option+Left click is still edge loop select, with OS-key set as 3 button modifier, which I think is pretty nice.

I wish there was a way to disable the Windows key while in Blender so that it could be the 3-button modifier like in macOS.